# Images not able to view in JSP page

Tags: html, image, jsp

I am trying to get images in my jsp page, I have put my images in 'webcontent/images/bp.jpg'.but while running it is just showing a icon like image not the exact image.

Below is my code:

```
<a href="productdetails.jsp"><img src="/application/WebContent/image/Chrysanthemum.jpg"  height="60" width="60"></a>
```

[image]

error is:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<img src="images/bp.jpg">
```

This will show your image with original image size. If you want to set height,width then you can use it as per your size dimensions.

Now it should work

Comment: still I'm getting the image in the same way

Comment: I have edited and modified the code. Check now it will surely work now.

Comment: Yes , It Works ... Thank You

Answer (score 0):

ok wait a min, try with online image. if online image is working, then its sure you are giving path wrongly, else there is some other issue..

[image]

This image code is

```
<img src="https://lh5.ggpht.com/Gw-GP112z9aDGInAQGMZ7QJUhYdTxsevG2NkrZnI2JZw6Yk7FrnEIkF3g-PSJdLa5FM=w300">
```

Comment: check if you are typing "images" or "image" inside the code and also check folder name also. Because it must be same at both place.

<img src="images/bp.jpg">

Comment: yeah..I'm giving images/bp.jpg only .where the folder also has name images. is the path where I have stored the imagesis correct?\

Comment: Welcome, Tick the right mark and like. So others can know the right answer.